# AngularJS UI-router, partial views and calling view from browser's location bar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, partial-views, angular-ui-router

I have this router entries

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

.state("main", {
    url: "/",
    views: {
         '' : { templateUrl: 'views/main.html' },
        'performance-ui-view@main': {
            templateUrl: 'views/gdreport.html',
            controller : 'GlobalDashboardController'
        }
    }
})

.state("main.odometer", {
url: "/odometer",
views: {
    'performance-ui-view@main': {
        templateUrl: 'views/odometer.html'
    }
}
})
```

It's working fine when using mouse. I get redirected to the page properly. Odometer page has always been our landing page until last week. Also, there is another AngularJS application that loads our application specifically they need to be in Odometer page. Last week, we received a new design from our UI designer. I changed the menus as well as the landing page. It's not odometers anymore. Our QA tester found this as a bug which is correct.

So I tried commenting out the line $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); so I can see the path on the browser location. Then I tried these calls on my browser with no luck. It always go to gdreport.html and sometimes even blank.

```
http://localhost:9000/#/odometer
http://localhost:9000/#//odometer
http://localhost:9000/odometer
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I learned something and I implemented the code but now our API services are returning 503. LOL! I can't test my new code

Comment: Finally they fixed the 503 issue. I tried my code but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point here is the *parent-child* **`url`** inheritance. There is a [working plunker with example](http://plnkr.co/edit/xxgAOJZWCXZYK3rszUSP?p=preview).

> A child `url` is built from its ancestors and its own `url` def. But we can override that behaviour.

In the example are states as above (main and main.odometer), plus brand new one called `main.other`. The new has different url definition - with leading sign **`^`**

```
// States
$stateProvider
  .state('main', {
      url: "/",
      ...
  })
  .state('main.odometer', {
      url: "/odometer", // will be //odometer
      ...
  })
  .state('main.other', {
      url: "^/other",   // will start from the root /other
      ...
  })
```

So, in this scenario, these links will have these url:

```
  <a ui-sref="main.odometer">- will be parent plus child url //odometer
  <a ui-sref="main.other"> - will result in /other
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xxgAOJZWCXZYK3rszUSP?p=preview)

The doc:

#### [Absolute Routes (^)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#absolute-routes-)

> If you want to have absolute url matching, then you need to prefix your url string with a special symbol **'^'**.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('contacts', {
     url: '/contacts',
     ...
  })
  .state('contacts.list', {
     url: '^/list',
     ...
  });
```

Comment: That's how I figured it out last night. I think I mentioned it on the other post I created. I also updated my view and changed ui-view so that it's empty.

Comment: If you say that this is working for you, and you understand it - great!

Comment: I encountered one issue though just right now. I made a call to http://localhost:9000/dashboard and I got a 404. This code didn't redirect me $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/view/dashboard'); However when my call contains # key even if the path is non-existent, the redirect works well.

Comment: I was thinking of configuring Apache to handle it but I'm not sure if that's a good idea. The 404 actually was provided by Apache

Comment: In case, your apache is configured well, check the base element and its href attribute. In my plunker I have to configure it with js, usually "/" should work

Comment: Yup, I got it working using Fallbackresource directive and not rewrite rule :)